# How to use form validation set rule in codeignter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

I am using Codeigniter 4 and try to validate my form, but I got stuck here

my controller codes:

```
public function create_project()
{
    $validation = \Config\Services::validation();

    //* Setting validation rules
    $validation->setRules([
        'project_name' => ['label' => 'Project Name', 'rules' => 'required'],
        'description' => ['label' => 'Comments', 'rules' => 'required']
    ]);

    if($validation->getErrors())
    {
        echo "We have errors";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No errors";
    }
}
```

When I leave the project name field and also the description field blank this code returns NO errors meaning the boolean is false, which I just don't understand?

Comment: Check user guide from official codeigniter website http://pneskin2.nekoget.com/codeigniter/4/user_guide/libraries/validation.html#form-validation-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html

Please refer to the above link.

```
$validation->withRequest($this->request)
       ->run();
```

You have not run the validation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your method is that you have set the rules BUT you did not carry on the validation. In order to carry on the validation you need to use validate() method

```
      $validation = \Config\Services::validation();

      //* Setting validation rules
      $validation->setRules([
          'project_name' => ['label' => 'Project Name', 'rules' => 'required'],
          'description' => ['label' => 'Comments', 'rules' => 'required']
      ]);
      // This is where validation will start
      if (!$this->validate([])) {

        echo "We have errors";
         var_dump($validation->getErrors());

     }else {
        echo 'Passed'
      }
```

I hope this answers your question.

a tip for you when you code using codeigniter4

Model has its on validation 
controller has its on validation 
using these are much much simpler that activating the validation library and trying to use it.